# comparing $R^2$ across two data sets

Tags: aic, r-squared

I have a set of covariates that characterize the type of experience a worker has (industry experience, general management experience, etc), and I am regressing compensation on these measures of experience.  For each worker, I have his/her prior job's compensation, and the compensation for the very next job he/she took.  I would like to see if my regressors do better job of explaining log(compensation) in the placed job condition or the prior job condition.  I am using OLS.

I have run regression models for prior and placed, using the same DV and the same set of IVs for the same population, with the models differring by if it pertains to prior or placed compensation.

Is there a test to evaluate for which of these models are the predictors better at explaining the variance in compensation?  Based on some research, there seems no statistical test to evaluate differences in $R^2$ or AIC.

In this context, I am not trying to select the better model, but I'm trying to provide evidence that certain measures of experience are better predictors in either the prior or the placed jobs.

Comment: Meng et. al. has published [a method](http://psycnet.apa.org/psycinfo/1992-15158-001) on comparing $R^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I asked a similar question yesterday and have been looking into it. I think I may have found a solution.

In Cohen, Cohen, West, and Aiken (2003), P. 88, they discuss constructing confidence intervals for differences between independent ***R<sup>2</sup>***

Here is the example they gave:

> For our running example of 62 cases (University *V*), we found the
>   *R<sup>2</sup><sub>V</sub>* = .5032 for the *k* = 4 IVs. For the same IVs in University *W*, where *n* = 143, assume that
>   *R<sup>2</sup><sub>w</sub>* = .2108. The difference is .5032 — .2108 = .2924. Since these are different groups that were independently
>   sampled, we can find *CI*s and perform null hypothesis significance
>   tests on this difference, using the *SE* of the difference. As we have
>   seen for other statistics, this is simply the square root of the sum
>   of the *SE<sup>2</sup>s* of the two *R<sup>2</sup>s*. We found the
>   *SE<sup>2</sup>*  for *V* to be .006461 in the previous section, and assume we find the *SE<sup>2</sup>* for *W* to be .003350.
>   Substituting,
>
> *SE<sub>R</sub><sup>2</sup><sub><sub>V</sub></sub> - <sub>R</sub><sup>2</sup><sub><sub>W</sub></sub>* =
>   SQRT(*SE<sub>R</sub><sup>2</sup><sub><sub>V</sub></sub>* +
>   *<sub>R</sub><sup>2</sup><sub><sub>w</sub></sub>*)
>
> The approximate 95% me = 2(.0825) = .1650, so the approximate 95% CI
>   for a nil hypothesis significance test = .2924 ± .1650, from .13 to
>   .46. Since the 95% CI does not include 0, the difference between the
>   universities' R<sup>2</sup>s is significant at the alpha = .05 level.

In order to calculate the SE<sup>2</sup> of R<sup>2</sup> they provide this formula:

> SE<sup>2</sup><sub>R<sup>2</sup></sub> = [4 *
>   *R<sup>2</sup>*(1-*R<sup>2</sup>*)<sup>2</sup>(*n*-*k*-1)<sup>2</sup>] / [(*n<sup>2</sup>*-1)(*n*+3)]

Additionally, they report:

> 95% confidence intervals using exact t values are routinely reported
>   in the literature. Alternatively,one may opt to use some other
>   probability, such as 80%, as providing reasonable bounds for the
>   purposes of the study. In recognition of the fairly rough
>   approximation provided by any of these limits, one may use the
>   approximate constant multipliers (tc) of the SEs for the desired
>   degree of inclusion of Section 2.8.2:
>
> ---
>
> *CI*__99%_____95%_____80%_____2.3
>
> t<sub>c</sub>__2.6_______2_______1.3_______1
>
> ---
>
> The 80% me for *R<sup>2</sup>* = 1.3(.0804) = .1045, so the approximate 80% CI is .503 ± .104,from .40 to .61. (The 95% me = 2
>   (.0804) = .161, so the approximate 95% CI for *R<sup>2</sup>* is .503
>   ±.161, from .34 to .66.)

I hope that helps.

EDIT - I forgot to mention that using the 95% CI might not be testing at a .05 significance level. [This article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC524673/) suggests it's more like 83% or 84%